# How to modify the domain of an equation?

Tags: graphing-functions

How can I modify the equation of say $y=sin(x)$ s.t
for $x<a, y<0$,
for $a<x<b, y=sin(x)$
and for $x>b, y<0$?

Basically I want an equation to only appear on the interval $[a;b]$. In other words, shrinking down the domain to the $[a;b]$ interval by modifying the equation itself.

Comment: From a math standpoint, just define $f: [a, b] →ℝ$, with $x ↦ \sin(x)$.

Comment: It is not clear to me, what the value of the function is supposed to be for $x < a$ or $x>b$. Not defined or some specific value less than $0$.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the "characteristic function". It is sometimes denoted by $\mathbb{1}$ or $\chi$:
$\chi_A (x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x ∈ A \\ 0 \text{ if } x \not\in A \end{cases}$
Here $A$ can be any set, for example $A = [a, b]$.